# How to troubleshoot MaxConcurrentSessions exceeded in IIS hosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm way out of my comfort zone so bear with me on providing the relevant information. We have just moved a IIS hosted WCF service to a new server and clients calling this service started experiencing timeouts. It does ok for about 10 minutes after recycling the app pool and then everything begins timing out. We enabled WCF tracing where I can see that its saying the MaxConcurrentSessions has been exceeded. The documentation says that value defaults to 2 x [# of processors] so it should be 200 for us.

The server is behind a load balancer, but is currently the only server. We notice the connections hang out at around 6 per second in Performance Monitor but will climb up to around 30 when the timeouts happen and continue climbing up from there.

The clients are connecting using a `wsHttpBinding` `TransportWithMessageCredential` security. The service validates the credentials provided in the message using the asp.net membership provider in a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` configured for use on the server binding behavior. The clients do not enable `reliableSession` on their bindings. The service uses the default `SessionMode` and `InstanceContextMode` which I believe are `Allowed` and `PerSession` respectively? We do not call `Close` on the service proxies because in past investigation, I've found this only sets a flag on the option preventing it from being re-used and ours always go out of scope anyway...but now doing testing to see if this does close the connection.

If I'm interpreting the WCF trace log correctly (and I don't understand the majority of what I'm reading there) it appears we are processing around 30-40 messages per minute and that each request is completed in less than 300ms (usually much less, on rare occasions nearly 1s.) I determined the number of messages by counting the `Processing message n` messages over a few 1 min spans. So if we're getting 40 per minute and it takes 100s for those connections/sessions to timeout and close, we would still only have about 68 open at once before the first ones begin to time out. Not close to the 200 limit. Does the connection for a single client request get more than one session?

The strange thing is we didn't have any timeouts before and copied the service and web.config straight over to the new server. I believe the server and IIS versions were upgraded (server 2016, IIS 10.) Can you please help me identify and provide the relevant information to track down the problem causing these timeouts?

**Edit**:
From my reading, everything seems to indicate that the client must call `Close` otherwise the server will leave the connection open until it times out. However, in our test, we see one connection created in perf. mon. but it remains open after `Close` has been called anyway. So I can't determine if the need to call close is a rumor or if we are misinterpretting our monitoring. The real test would be to call `Close` everywhere and see if it eliminates our timeouts.

After increasing our `MaxConcurrentSessions` to 400, in performance monitor, we saw the number of concurrent sessions and instances steadily rise by about 1 per second up to about 225 where it finally leveled off and it's hovering around there. So it seems like sessions are not being closed.

Comment: Did you compare the app pool's advanced settings with the old server?

Comment: Yes, did not see any differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well we figured it out. There was nothing that just popped up and told us what the problem was and it took a lot of brain storming, but here's what we did:

1. Enabled WCF tracing. Went through the traces and was able to understand enough to basically see that the traffic didn't look out of the ordinary. All of the events seemed to be for the expected amount and types of service calls. Viewing in [svctraceviewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe), It didn't seem to be a DOS attack or anything like that. We just used the default configuration from that link, but it looks like it can be very customized to provide the specific information you're after if you know what that is.
2. What really helped in this case was finding the [WCF Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/performance-counters/index). Initially we were using ASP.NET performance counters to look at sessions open which was not the right metric. [This codeproject guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431917/WCF-Service-Performance-Monitoring-using-Perfmon) helped us enable the WCF performance counters to give us an insight into the number of sessions and the limit in real time.
3. It also helped to brush up on how WCF sessions and instances are related as well as creation of a security context:

   - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188749/WCF-Sessions-Brief-Introduction
   - http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009/01/wcf-performance-gearing-up-your-service.html
   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/hh273122(v=vs.100)

We were able to see the percentage of the max WCF sessions being used, and observed it climbing higher and higher towards the default limit of 200 (100 per processor) but eventually level off between 150 and 200. This leveling off, together with far more sessions existing at a given time than the average number of requests per minute seen in our WCF tracing, indicated that sessions were closing but seemed to be remaining open until they timed out rather than closing as soon as the server completed the request.

Somewhere on Stack Overflow, that I've been unable to find, I once asked about the purpose of the `[ClientBase<TChannel>.Close][4]` method (a.k.a. the close method of a WCF service proxy) and, somewhat incorrectly, came to the conclusion that all it did is set a flag on the proxy object marking it closed so that it couldn't be used again. The documentation's description of the method seems in line with that:

> Causes the `ClientBase<TChannel>` object to transition from its current
>   state into the closed state.

Well at the point that I would call `Close`, my references always just go out of scope anyway allowing garbage collection to clean it up so that seemed pointless. But I think a key factor was that that was regarding basicHttpBindings which are stateless. In this case, we are using wsHttpBindings which are stateful which means the server leaves keeps the session and leaves the connection open after it completes the request so that subsequent calls from the client can be made on the same connection. So, though I couldn't find any documentation or track down in the source code where it happens, it seems WCF clients **must** call `Close` on their service proxy after they make their last request in order to tell the server it can close the connection and free up that session slot. I didn't have the opportunity to look for a message sent to the server upon calling `Close` to do this, but we were able to observe, using the Performance Counter, the number of sessions dropping from 1 to 0 where before it would remain at 1 after our client called the service.

But we're saying a WCF client, who we may have no control over, is able to harm server performance and possibly create a denial of service if they aren't diligent in their coding and remembering to call `Close` and the server has no control over its own performance?? That sounds like a recipe for disaster. Well there are two things you can do on the server to mitigate this. First you can increase the max number of sessions. In our case we were hovering around 175 but occasionally under traffic spikes exceeding the 200. We bumped it up to 800 temporarily to ensure we wouldn't exceed the max. The trade-off is dedicating more server resources to holding those sessions that will probably never be used again until they time out. Luckily, the server also controls the timeout. The service can control the length these sessions are held open using the [`ReceiveTimeout` and the `InactivityTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout?view=netframework-4.6.2). Both default to 10 minutes but the lesser of the two will be used. If you're thinking, "Receive timeout sounds wrong. That controls the amount of time the service can take to receive a large message", you're not alone. However, [that's incorrect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding). On the server side:

> ReceiveTimeout – used by the Service Framework Layer to initialize the session-idle timeout which controls how long a session can be idle before timing out.

And on the client-side it is not used. So we set our `ReceiveTimeout` to 30 seconds and the sessions dropped significantly. That may have actually been too low because some spots in code that do re-use the service proxy (making multiple calls in a loop for instance, or doing some data processing in between calls) are now getting an error when trying to call the service after the session has been closed. So you will have to find the right balance. But best practice, it seems, is to close your connections.

One gotcha to watch out for is using `Dispose` on your service proxy. I had always tried typing `.dispo` to see if intellisense would popup the `Dispose` method on my proxy and found that it didn't so assumed it didn't implement `IDisposable` and didn't need to be closed or disposed. It turns out it does implement `IDisposable` but it does it explicitly so you'd have to cast it as an `IDisposable` to call `Dispose` on it. But wait! Don't go putting your proxy in a `using` statement just yet. The implementation of `Dispose` sillily just calls `Close` on the proxy which will throw an exception if the proxy is in the faulted state (i.e. if a service call threw an exception). So you can't safely do something like this:

```
using(MyWcfClient proxy = new MyWcfClient())
{
    try
    {
        proxy.Calculate();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

because if `Calculate` throws an exception, the closing bracket of the `using` block will also throw an exception when it tries to dispose your proxy. Instead you just have to call `Close` after your last service method call. Evidently you can also call `Abort` in the `catch`, but I'm not sure if that actually communicates with the server to end the session.

```
MyWcfClient proxy = new MyWcfClient

try
{
    proxy.Calculate();
    proxy.Close();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    proxy.Abort();
}
```

### Addendum

We surmise the reason we started experiencing this when moving servers and were not experiencing it before is we were using Barracuda products before and are now using Oracle and perhaps the old load balancer or firewall was closing open connections for us.